# PySpark function behaving different between mapValues and filter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working in spark using pyspark.  I have an rdd that is of the format `[(key, (num, (min, max, count))),....]` when I use the lambda below

```
t = fullBids.filter(lambda (value, stats): (stats[2] > 10 and stats[0] < value and value < stats[1]))
```

it errors out with

```
tuple index out of range
```

but when I use it in a mapValues call it runs successfully, returning either True or False correctly.

```
ti = fullBids.mapValues(lambda (value, stats): (stats[2] > 10 and stats[0] < value and value < stats[1]))
```

I would expect the filter to work, but it isn't. Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `filter`, `value` is the key of the key-value pair RDD while `stats` is the value of the RDD (`(num, (min, max, count))`), that's why you have a `tuple index out of range`.

When you call `mapValues`, `value` is `num` while `stats` is `(min, max, count)`. Infact the `mapValues` transformation passes each value in the key-value pair RDD.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. It is not obvious to me what is passed in the rdd functions. Is there a good source for this information?

Comment: I had the same problem, I suggest you the "Learning Spark" book which is very clear and full of examples in both python, scala and java.

Answer (score 2):

If you decompose your RDD format

```
(key, (num, (min, max, count)))

key = value
(num, (min, max, count)) = stats
num = stats[0]
(min, max, count) = stats[1]
min = stats[1][0]
max = stats[1][1]
count = stats[1][2]
```

So your `stats[2]` is out of range